# Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'UIDatePicker'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, syntax-error, uidatepicker

Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'UIDatePicker', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform. How to fix it? I want to make app for count days from date and show it on badge.

```
- (IBAction)setDate:(UIDatePicker *)countdownDate;{

daysRemaining = countdownDate + todaysDate;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = daysRemaining;}
```

See the detailed error in below snapshot:-

[image: Error]

Comment: What you wrote doesn't even make sense, semantically, never mind the syntactical issues.  What does adding a date picker to a date even mean?  If you want to do something with the date the date picker has currently selected, you need to access its date property.  After that, you need to learn Objective-C, because you can't just add two NSDates together.  You need to read the NSDate and NSCalendar references.